# error: call to 'CrossProduct' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, c++11

I have created a template class named Vector in a header file, say foo.h. Here is a MWE of how I defined the template class and functions operating on objects of the class

```
#ifndef FOO_H_                                                                                                                                                                     
#define FOO_H_

namespace foo {
  template <class T, int dimensions> class Vector {
    private:
      T component_[dimensions];
    public:
      Vector(const T& a = 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++)
          component_[i] = a;
      } // default/scalar constructor

      const T& operator[](int i) const{
        return component_[i];
      } // read-only ith component of the vector


      void set(int i, const T& a) {
        component_[i] = a;
      } // change ith component of the vector
  };

  typedef Vector<double, 3> Point3D;

  template <class T, int dimensions> T
  operator*(const Vector<T,dimensions>& u,
      const Vector<T, dimensions>& v) {
    T sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++)
      sum += u[i] * v[i];
    return sum;
  } // vector vector inner/dot product

  Point3D CrossProduct(const Point3D&, const Point3D&);
  double ScalarTripleProduct(const Point3D&, const Point3D&,
      const Point3D&);
  Point3D VectorTripleProduct(const Point3D&, const Point3D&,
      const Point3D&);
}

#endif  // FOO_H_
```

This is the end of foo.h. I then defined the three functions in foo.cpp operating on objects of the template class in foo.h. Here is the code below.

```
#include "foo.h"                                                                                                                                                                   

using namespace foo;

Point3D CrossProduct(const Point3D& a, const Point3D& b) {
  Point3D c;
  c.set(0, a[1] * b[2] - a[2] * b[1]);
  c.set(1, a[2] * b[0] - a[0] * b[2]);
  c.set(2, a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0]);
  return c;
} // vector cross product: a X b, defined only for 3D vectors

double ScalarTripleProduct(const Point3D& a, const Point3D& b,
    const Point3D& c) {
  return a * CrossProduct(b, c);
} // scalar triple product: a . (b X c), defined only for 3D vectors

Point3D VectorTripleProduct(const Point3D& a,
    const Point3D& b, const Point3D& c) {
  return CrossProduct(a, CrossProduct(b, c));;
} // vector triple product: a X (b X c), defined only for 3D vectors
```

Now when I try to compile foo.cpp with `g++ foo.cpp -c`, I get the following errors

```
foo.cpp:15:13: error: call to 'CrossProduct' is ambiguous
        return a * CrossProduct(b, c);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./foo.h:35:10: note: candidate function
        Point3D CrossProduct(const Point3D&, const Point3D&);
                ^
foo.cpp:5:9: note: candidate function
Point3D CrossProduct(const Point3D& a, const Point3D& b) {
        ^
foo.cpp:20:25: error: call to 'CrossProduct' is ambiguous
        return CrossProduct(a, CrossProduct(b, c));;
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./foo.h:35:10: note: candidate function
        Point3D CrossProduct(const Point3D&, const Point3D&);
                ^
foo.cpp:5:9: note: candidate function
Point3D CrossProduct(const Point3D& a, const Point3D& b) {
        ^
2 errors generated.
        ^
```

I am not sure about what went wrong. Could you please help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: I [can't reproduce this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/snTohjdr1) after commenting out the uses of `operator[]` and adding an `operator*`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include a member function, I have included it now.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I also can't reproduce it. How do you compile?

Comment: I apologize once again for the issues with the code. I have created a MWE and included the errors when I was compiling with g++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of `Point3D CrossProduct(const Point3D&, const Point3D&);` inside `namespace foo` and the definition of `Point3D CrossProduct(const Point3D&, const Point3D&) { /*...*/ }` in the global namespace refer to different functions (the former one having no definition).

Note that `using namespace foo;` only affects name resolution, but does not automatically place subsequent definition(s) in any namespace other than the one explicitly specified, in this case the global namespace.

To fix, make sure to define the function in the same namespace where it was declared using either of the following.

```
  Point3D foo::CrossProduct(const Point3D& a, const Point3D& b) {
    /*...*/
  }
```

```
namespace foo {
  Point3D CrossProduct(const Point3D& a, const Point3D& b) {
    /*...*/
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation, this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by you compiling both files:

You’re doing

```
g++ -o foo foo.h foo.cpp
```

(Replace g++ with your compiler)

This will make foo.h appear twice (it’s included in foo.cpp) and so you’ve got two functions that do the same and the compiler cannot decide which one to choose.

Header files should not be compiled like that, only included.